# Hibernate @OneToMany EAGER doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship

I have two entities, `topics` and `posts` respectively. Here's many `posts` for one `topics`.

So i had set up `topics` to `OneToMany`:

```
class topics implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "topic")
    @OrderBy("date DESC")
    private List<posts> postsList;
    public List<posts> getPostsList()
    {
        return this.postsList;
    }
}
```

In `posts` entity are not any specific settings for `topic` field, just typical `Integer`.

So problem is i can't fetch this `postsList` with `EAGER` fetch type, it will stay `LAZY` anyway:

```
topics theTopic = (topics) session.load(topics.class, topic);
List<posts> postsOfTopic = theTopic.getPostsList();
```

... the `List` contains one object now, but it's full of nulls.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Does the posts table contains foreign key to the topics table ?

Comment: The one object in the List is then a proxy Posts object lazily loaded. Right ?

Comment: @Shailendra, yeah and its null on each field. In debugger i see that it lazily loaded. Actually, my purpose is only to retrieve `List` from the entity. Maybe you know another approaches to get list full of actual data, not null filled?

Comment: It typically has null fields except a field "target" ( if i remember the name correctly) and as you expand that further in debugger you would find  the property values. Anyway you can try get method instead of load OR try fetch eager HQL query.

Comment: @Shailendra, yes, and i told you that these properties are nulls :) Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [session.load](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method typically returns a proxy whereas the [session.get](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method is guaranteed to return the initialized entity and would eagerly fetch collection if marked as such. Also there is option of using eager fetch HQL queries to eager load the associated collection.